# Every time I try to upgrade from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10, it fails

Tags: 13.04, 13.10, upgrade, partitioning

How do I add space to my `/boot` directory? Every time I try to  upgrade I am told that I need 20MB more space (for a total of about 80MB), and I have already run commands to free up all unused kernels and headers. I have 60MB free, and am currently using 40MB. I am really stuck. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use gparted to extend your /boot partition.

For more information refer this question 
[How do I resize my /boot partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280211/how-do-i-resize-my-boot-partition)

Comment: I have already tried gparted Karthik, thank you for your contribution though. What I did end up doing though, was backing up all of my important stuffs and what nots, and then I downloaded saucy salamander and used the start up disk creator to burn the .iso to my USB, then I booted to the USB. Once there, I chose install, answered the prompted information, revived my important stuffs from ubuntu one and my external hard drive, and finally formatted my USB. One ccould of course leave it on there if they wanted to boot into linux using the live USB on a different computer.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you choose to reinstall the entire system, when you could have easily increased the boot partition size and then upgraded.