# Unable to upgrade due to low disk space

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I am currently running version 15.10 of Ubuntu, and today system requested an upgrade to 16.04. I ran the upgrade but it stopped mid-way due to low disk space error. I cleaned up old kernels, leaving just the one I am currently running, but it still didn't make up enough space for the upgrade. Here is my current kernel list:

```
ii  linux-image-4.2.0-42-generic       4.2.0-42.49  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-42-generic 4.2.0-42.49  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                4.2.0.42.45  amd64        Generic Linux kernel image

ii  linux-headers-4.2.0-42         4.2.0-42.49  all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.2.0
ii  linux-headers-4.2.0-42-generic 4.2.0-42.49  amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic          4.2.0.42.45  amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
```

and here is the `df -h` result:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           388M  6,5M  381M   2% /run
/dev/dm-1       454G   15G  416G   4% /
tmpfs           1,9G  160K  1,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2       237M  119M  106M  53% /boot
/dev/sda1       511M  3,4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           388M   48K  388M   1% /run/user/1000
```

This is the error message (after the old kernel clean-up):

```
Not enough free disk space 

The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 183 M free 
space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 72,6 M of 
disk space on '/boot'. Empty your trash and remove temporary packages 
of former installations using 'sudo apt-get clean'.
```

I have tried `sudo apt-get clean` and my trash is empty. 
Is there anything else I can do to free more space in `/boot`?

Comment: Why is `/boot` mounted on a different partition?

Comment: I cannot answer that, I was not the one who installed the OS. Is there a way to switch it to `/dev/sda1` while avoiding a clean reinstall?

Comment: Hmm, possibly, but it could be pretty tricky.  Probably better to grow the partition, as @KratsYnot suggested.

Comment: Check out http://askubuntu.com/questions/280211/how-do-i-resize-my-boot-partition

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps resize the partition?

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280211/how-do-i-resize-my-boot-partition) suggests apt-get autoremove, if you have not tried that

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I haven't thought as far as resizing the partition. I will try that, cheers!