# Virtual machine memory full

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu, ram

The virtual hard disk of my virtual machine on Oracle virtualbox got full. Now I'm not able to do anything on it. Although, I added another hard disk but for it to work I have to configure it in disk management.

I just get a black screen which looks like a terminal but is not able to perform anything because there is no memory

Comment: Memory or disk? If disk - extend the virtual disk, boot in single user mode, enlarge the partition, and enlarge the filesystem.

Comment: I have extended the virtual disk but I don't know how to enlarge the file system without accessing the virtual machine

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot or from booting a live system (installer ISO "try out") https://askubuntu.com/questions/280211/how-do-i-resize-my-boot-partition