# Error while installing anything - /boot/

Tags: boot, apt, kernel

I'm new in ubuntu server or any server (in fact) probably I've done something wrong. I'm trying to install docker and when I run:

```
sudo apt-get install \
linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) \
linux-image-extra-virtual
```

I get this:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-83-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/xvda3
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-83-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-firmware
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've searched online and nothing worked, sadly. My kernel is 4.4.0-83-generic.
Thanks to all.

Comment: Probably the issue to address first is `gzip: stdout: No space left on device` : see for example [“gzip: stdout: No space left on device” while upgrading the kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223248/gzip-stdout-no-space-left-on-device-while-upgrading-the-kernel)